# BQ - No longer able to partition table in scheduled queries using run_time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I used to be able to partition my tables in big query using parameters in my table name when setting up a scheduled query by putting my table name and then adding {} brackets to add in the run_time for example my table name would like: mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}

This method is still outlined in the documentation [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#param-templating-syntax) however it seems like you can no longer do this (unless I am doing something wrong). The box that used to say table name has now been changed to table id and when trying to put the following in the table id mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"} - I get this error "Invalid table ID". If I remove the run_time parameters - it works however my table is no longer partitioned. Anyone know if this has actually been removed? Or if it is a bug? if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd love to hear what fix you get for this - the only thing that works for me is to click on 'Disable Editor Tabs' and revert back to the previous version of the Big Query UI.  This allows me to set up new schedule queries using `mytable_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}`

I then Enable the Editor tabs again - it's a huge faff

Comment: No fix so far however I will update if I find one. But thanks so much! This is perfect and at least gets me going again! :)